# Exposing a server's classpath/debug source lookup in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-wtp

I am developing an Eclipse plugin which provides an WST server adapter ( like Tomcat, Jetty, etc ) - [Sling IDE Tooling](https://sling.apache.org/documentation/development/ide-tooling.html).

The actual server is a Java application so it does have a classpath. I am interested in exposing that classpath to Eclipse so that

- users can see what is deployed on that server
- I can populate the source lookup path when debugging

I known how to find out what is deployed on the server, but how can I expose it to Eclipse?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`IVMConnector.connect` takes an `ILaunch` argument, which in turn holds a `ISourceLocator`. The source locator has a list of `ISourceContainer` instances.

The source container instances are built from a list of resolved `IRuntimeClasspathEntry`s. Some examples:

```
List<IRuntimeClasspathEntry> classpathEntries = new ArrayList<>();

// 1. Adding a IJavaProject as a classpath entry
classpathEntries.add(JavaRuntime.newProjectRuntimeClasspathEntry(javaProject));

// 2. Adding external jar files
classpathEntries.add(JavaRuntime.newArchiveRuntimeClasspathEntry(jarPath));

// 3. Adding a JRE entry
classpathEntries.add(JavaRuntime.computeJREEntry(launch.getLaunchConfiguration()));
```

The classpath entries then need to be resolved and converted to source containers

```
// 4. resolve the classpath entries
IRuntimeClasspathEntry[] resolved = JavaRuntime.resolveSourceLookupPath(classpathEntries.toArray(new IRuntimeClasspathEntry[0]), launch.getLaunchConfiguration());

// 5. convert them to source references
ISourceContainer[] containers = JavaRuntime.getSourceContainers(resolved));
```

At this point the source c